# How to display multiple items using puts?

Tags: ruby, class, puts, ruby-hash

I have written a Travel App with Tour Items and  I'm trying to display the order at the end.

When I use puts `@order_items` I get `{"SevendaySurfSportTour"=>2}` for two tours.

**I would like it to display**
`2 SevendaySurfSportTour` at the end. But I don't know how, any help would be good?

```
class TourOrder
    def initialize
        @order_items = Hash.new(0)
    end
    def add_item(name, quantity)
        @order_items[name] += quantity
    end
    def get_items
        return @order_items
    end

    def display
        puts "Thank you for coming!"
        puts @order_items
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@order_items` is a hash and what has printed out if the string representation of such a hash. When you want to format the output differently, then you have to implement that on your own – for example like this:

```
def display
  puts "Thank you for coming!"

  @order_items.each do |name, quantity|
    puts "#{quantity} #{name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Great it worked. Thanx I am learning new stuff everyday I guess. :)

Answer (score 0):

Below code works for you

```
class TourOrder
  def initialize
    @order_items = Hash.new(0)
  end
 
  def add_item(name, quantity)
    @order_items[name] += quantity
  end
 
  def get_items
    @order_items
  end

  def display
    puts "Thank you for coming!"
    puts items 
  end

  def items
    @order_items.collect{ |k, v| "#{v} #{k}"}
  end
end

t = TourOrder.new
t.add_item('SevendaySurfSportTour', 2)
t.add_item('Foo', 4)
t.add_item('Bar', 1)
t.display
=> Thank you for coming!
   2 SevendaySurfSportTour
   4 Foo
   1 Bar
```